# change child value from parent on timer elapse

Tags: c#, components, blazor

I have a simple parent-child component :

parent :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
        <ChildComponent RandomNumber="@RandomNumberX" ></ChildComponent>
    </div>
</div>
@code {

public double RandomNumberX = 0.1;

private Timer timer = new Timer();

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    timer.Interval = 3000;
    timer.Elapsed -= Set;
    timer.Elapsed += Set;
    timer.Start();
}

private void Set(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var rng = new Random();

    var x = rng.Next(500, 600);
    RandomNumberX = x;
}}
```

Child:

```
<svg height="100" width="100" style="position:absolute;  border-color: black; ">
    <g>
        <circle cx="50%" cy="25" r="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
        <text x="50%" y="50" text-anchor="middle">@RandomNumber</text>
    </g>
</svg>
@code {
[Parameter]
public double RandomNumber { get; set; }

protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
        
}
}
```

when running app "RandomNumber" show 0.1 and does not change while in parent component it changes on timer elapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimerElapsed is not a 'normal' Blazor lifecycle event. So it won't automatically trigger a re-render. (A ButtonClick event would, for example).

So you need to call StatehasChanged, and to cater for the possibility it's on another Thread you need to InvokeAsync that.

```
private async void Set(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var rng = new Random();

    var x = rng.Next(500, 600);
    RandomNumberX = x;
    await InvokeAsync(StatehasChnaged);
}
```

You should normally avoid `async void` but this is exactly the suituation it was created for.

Side note: `timer.Elapsed -= Set;` during Initialization is only half a solution.

Use  `@implements IDisposable` on the top of your page and add

```
public void Dispose()
{
    timer.Elapsed -= Set;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I animated a SVG clock a little while back that does this:

**Note**: The use of dispose and how I reduce the calculations to only when needed by checking for a second change.
`Clock.razor`

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <div class="time-sm">@timeZone.Id</div>
    <svg width="@Size" height="@Size" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
        <circle cx="@center" cy="@center" r="@radius" fill="@FaceColor" />
        <ClockHand Angle="hourAngle" Color="@HourColor" Width="50" Length="0.9" />
        <ClockHand Angle="minuteAngle" Color="@MinuteColor" Width="30" Length="0.95" />
        <ClockHand Angle="secondAngle" Color="@SecondColor" Width="20" Length="1" />
    </svg>
    <div class="time-sm">@currentSecond.DateTime.ToShortTimeString()</div>
    <div class="time-sm">@currentSecond.DateTime.ToString("dddd")</div>
</div>
```

`Clock.razor.cs`

```
public partial class Clock : ComponentBase, IDisposable
{
    internal const int radius = 500;
    internal const int size = 1000;
    internal const int center = size / 2;
    private double secondAngle = 0;
    private double minuteAngle = 0;
    private double hourAngle = 0;
    private TimeZoneInfo timeZone;
    private DateTimeOffset currentSecond;
    private readonly System.Timers.Timer timer = new();

    [Parameter]
    public int Size { get; set; } = 50;

    [Parameter]
    public string FaceColor { get; set; } = "#f5f5f5";

    [Parameter]
    public string HourColor { get; set; } = "blue";

    [Parameter]
    public string MinuteColor { get; set; } = "green";

    [Parameter]
    public string SecondColor { get; set; } = "red";

    [Parameter]
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TimeZone) is true)
        {
            timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        }
        else
        {
            timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZone);
        }

        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        UpdateClock();
        timer.Start();
    }
    public static DateTime GmtToPacific(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTime,
            TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"));
    }
    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateClock();
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private void UpdateClock()
    {
        const double radiansPer60 = 360 / 60 * Math.PI / 180;
        const double radiansPer12 = 360 / 12 * Math.PI / 180;

        var currentTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.Now, timeZone);
        var roundedSencond = new DateTimeOffset(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, currentTime.Day, currentTime.Hour, currentTime.Minute, currentTime.Second, default);

        if (roundedSencond != currentSecond)
        {

            currentSecond = roundedSencond;

            var seconds = currentTime.Second;
            var minutes = currentTime.Minute;
            var hours = currentTime.Hour % 12;

            secondAngle = seconds * radiansPer60;
            minuteAngle = minutes * radiansPer60 + secondAngle / 60;
            hourAngle = hours * radiansPer12 + minuteAngle / 12;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (timer is not null)
        {
            timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

`ClockHand.razor`

```
<line x1="500" y1="500" x2="@X" y2="@Y" style="stroke:@Color;stroke-width:@Width" />
```

`ClockHand.razor.cs`

```
public partial class ClockHand : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public double Angle { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public double Length { get; set; } = 1;

    [Parameter]
    public string Color { get; set; } = "black";

    [Parameter]
    public int Width { get; set; }

    double X => Math.Sin(Angle) * Clock.radius * Length + Clock.center;
    double Y => Math.Cos(Angle) * -Clock.radius * Length + Clock.center;
}
```

`Useage`

```
<Clock TimeZone="Australia/Sydney" />
```

or

```
<Clock />
```

[image]