# How do properties cause pages to update in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've just finished my first non-trivial test app in Blazor WebAssembly. Blazor is impressive stuff, but I don't find it easy to reason about how changes to properties cause updates to the DOM - for example, where the property is referenced in a Razor component.

```
<div>@SomeProperty</div>
```

```
public int SomeProperty {get;set;}
```

In WPF, it's very easy to reason about how changes flow and cause rendering changes because they're triggered by events and DependencyProperty changes. You can see these and bind to them. In Blazor, somehow you can change a property value and the page updates. The precise mechanism behind this is a bit like magic. As a result, it can be hard to reason about how to remove unnecessary updates for complex components.

Can anyone explain the underpinnings of this topic?

Is there any documentation or video that goes into depth on this area of Blazor?

Comment: Summary of the other two good answers: if you change something, you need to call for a refresh with `StateHasChanged().`  The confusion comes because sometimes `StateHasChanged()` is called automatically, giving a sense of inconsistency: "Well, A B and C refreshed the UI, but D didn't.  Why?"

Comment: The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-6.0) has a dedicated page for rendering.

Comment: What happens is perfectly logical.  The issue is a lack of knowledge and understanding - it's not a simple subject.  Hence your question.   The official documentation isn't great.  I've "tried" to succinctly summarise how and why in my answer below, but I may not have succeeded!  There's a longer version of the answer on Github.

Comment: Both answers are below great. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In Blazor, somehow you can change a property value and the page updates.

Not exactly. The property itself has nothing to do with this. You can for instance [update it with a Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70549394/60761) and you won't see the UI changing.

But usually you will set the property in response to a ButtonClick or other Blazor (lifecycle) event. And those are [bracketed with calls to StateHasChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137160/60761). In a Timer event or other non-Blazor event you will have to call StateHasChanged() yourself.

`StateHasChanged()` requests (not: performs) a UI update. That update will happen after the event or during the next `await`.

> As a result, it can be hard to reason about how to remove unnecessary updates for complex components.

That is different from `<div>@SomeProperty</div>`.

When you have `<Details ItemId="itemId" />` and `itemId` is a basic type like int or a string then Details will only be re-rendered when itemId changes.

But when it is `<Details Item="item" />` and item is some complex type then the component will always be rerendered along with the parent page.

I have sometimes used the following pattern in the Details component, when Item has no mutable properties, ie for `<Details Item="selectedItem" />`:

```
[Parameter]
public Item Item { get; set; } = new();

int oldId = 0;

protected override bool ShouldRender()
{
    if (oldId != Item.Id)
    {
        oldId = Item.Id;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation 

Answer (score 10):

> Can anyone explain the underpinnings of this topic?

To understand the update process you need to understand Components.  I'll try and keep this short!

All components must implement `IComponent`.  `ComponentBase` is an implementation of `IComponent`.

```cs
public interface IComponent
{
    void Attach(RenderHandle renderHandle);
    Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters);
}
```

The important bits of a RenderHandle are:

```cs
public readonly struct RenderHandle
{
    public Dispatcher Dispatcher ....
    //....
    public void Render(RenderFragment renderFragment)
    {
        //....
        _renderer.AddToRenderQueue(_componentId, renderFragment);
        //...
    }
}
```

And a RenderFragment is:

```cs
public delegate void RenderFragment(RenderTreeBuilder builder);
```

A `Renderer` manages the render process. It holds The DOM (what gets rendered by the Browser) represented as a RenderTree.  When the Renderer attaches a component to the RenderTree, the Renderer creates a `RenderHandle` and passes it to the component by calling `Attach`.  The Component uses this `RenderHandle` to communicate with the Renderer.  The Renderer communicates with the component by calling `SetParametersAsync`.

Components "Render" by calling the `Render` method on the `RenderHandle` and passing a `RenderFragment` delegate.

Here's a simple render fragment:

```cs
protected RenderFragment HelloWorld => (RenderTreeBuilder builder) =>
{
    builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
    builder.AddContent(1, "Hello Blazor");
    builder.CloseElement();
};
```

Calling `Render` on the `RenderHandle` **DOES NOT** render the component.  It just places the render fragment on the Renderer's queue.  When the Renderer runs the fragment it checks for component parameter changes referenced by other components.  It calls `SetParametersAsync` on any components where their reference parameters have changed.

`StateHasChanged` is a `ComponentBase` method.  `StateHasChanged` is called internally by the Blazor UI event handler, so you rarely need to call it manually.  If you do, ask yourself why? Your logic may be wrong!  It looks like this:

```cs
var task = InvokeAsync(EventMethod);
StateHasChanged();
if (!task.IsCompleted)
{
    await task;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

The main exception is a normal event handler.  If the event updates data in the component you need to trigger a manual update by calling `StateHasChanged`.  This is the standard pattern.

```cs
private void OnSomethingChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    => this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
```

Notes:

1. `StateHasChanged` has a mechanism for detecting if a render fragment is already queued, so it doesn't queue multiple renders.
2. `InvokeAsync` ensures a task is run on the UI thread.  It uses the `Dispatcher` provided on the `RenderHandle`.
3. When the Renderer checks for parameter changes, any object is considered dirty as there's no simple way for the Renderer to check equality.
4. The Renderer only services it's queue when it gets thread time to do so.  If you run a long sequence of synchronous code in say a button click handler nothing happens till the synchronous code completes.

Delve into `ComponentBase` if you want to dig further - [You can view the code here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs).

Comment: This is a really helpful dive into this. Really clarifies things for me.